# Why the value of the variable is not changed out the method

Tags: dart, flutter

Why the value of the variable blueColor is not changed out the method typeSelected()

```
 bool blueColor = true;
typeSelected(){
  setState(() {
    blueColor = !blueColor;
    print("run:");
    print("blueColor:$blueColor"); // changing
  });
}
print("blueColor:$blueColor"); //(true) without change
```

this where I want to change

```
 GestureDetector(
     onTap: () => typeSelected(),
        child: Container(
             width: 60,
             height: 60,
             padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
             margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 5),
             decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.brown.shade500,
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                border: blueColor ? 
                    border: blueColor ? Border.all(
                    color:Colors.white70,width:0,style:BorderStyle.solid)
                    :Border.all(color:Colors.blue,width:2,style: BorderStyle.solid)
                              ),
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you show where are you declaring that `blueColor` ?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the static keyword in the variable so that when you will change the value of any variable, it will reflect throughout your project or program

```
  static bool blueColor = true;
```

the rest code will be the same

```
typeSelected(){
   setState(() {
    blueColor = !blueColor;
    print("run:");
  });
  }
 print("blueColor:$blueColor");
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: it didn't Work .